# excel sumif function not functioning properly

Tags: excel, sum

I am trying to get the sum between two dates, but the sumif function is doing it wrong. The answer is suppose to be 18, but it gives me 31. What am I doing wrong? please see picture below:

[image]

Comment: are you sure all your dates are sorted?

Answer (score 1):

The formula didn't detect the dates because the data was formatted as a string. That's what caused the wrong result.

Comment: The author answered the question.